# Why is is showing error in rotating the strings of larger length?

Tags: c++, string, loops

my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n ;
    cin >> n;


    string s1 , s2 , s3;
    cin >> s1 >> s2;

    string s = s1 + s1;

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; s3 != s2 ; i++) {

        // int a = s.find()

        s3 = s.substr( i , s1.length() );

        count++;
    }

    cout << count - 1;

    return 0;
}
```

In this when I try to rotate the small sized string it is working fine but when I tried with some large length string it is showing error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 227) > this->size() (which is 226)
```

I'm not understanding what is happening as with the string length of 20 or 30 it is working fine but when then string length is over the 110 it is showing this type of error.

Also this testcase is showing error

113
ndafmffmuuwjzqpquwjhuftohawpfegsjvnxwipwqlswvawogjuyiqtzsgpwgosegmuuhpzwchejuiitumyescxxyecnsatcbfpseqzowvdjyvchg
zqpquwjhuftohawpfegsjvnxwipwqlswvawogjuyiqtzsgpwgosegmuuhpzwchejuiitumyescxxyecnsatcbfpseqzowvdjyvchgavqnonmkwgqp

Comment: As for me then I do not understand what this code is doing.:) In my opinion it does not make a sense.

Comment: You're calling `substr` with an index above the length of the string (227 in this case, while the string only has length 226) - so `i` in your for loop managed to count up to 227, and because this is 1 larger than the length of the string, you get a `std::out_of_range` exception [like documented](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Please show some simple working and non working examples of input and expected output vs. actual output.

Comment: Why do you assume that `for (int i = 0 ; s3 != s2 ; i++) {` is guaranteed to terminate? (That there is the case where `s2` is equal to `s3`?) `s` initialized with `s1 + s1` so there is no reason why `s2` and `s3` should have something in common?

Comment: The condition will never become false in your problematic test case.(It looks like this could be solved with `s.find(s2)` and no loop.)

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Jabberwocky
My question is this                                                                                                              You are given a string and a number of queries to perform. For each query you have to rotate the string either left or right. For example, if the string is abcde, rotating left by 1 character will give bcdea. Now rotating again right by 1 character will give abcde back.

Find the resultant string after performing all the queries.

Comment: @Chaitanya please **[edit]** your question and put all relevant information into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple your `for` loop  has condition which is never `false` for this input. So you are increasing `i` beyond size of `s` (double of size of `s1`).

Note common part of this two strings is: `zqpquwjhuftohawpfegsjvnxwipwqlswvawogjuyiqtzsgpwgosegmuuhpzwchejuiitumyescxxyecnsatcbfpseqzowvdjyvchg`.
Difference is:

- `s1` has in front: `ndafmffmuuwj`
- `s2` has in backL: `avqnonmkwgqp`

So `s1` is not rotation of `s2` that is why codition in `for` is never `fasle`.

This is the reason `std::basic_string::substr` throws an exception.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v9dWT3TbK).
[Some fix](https://godbolt.org/z/sMj4PhdPc).

And here is [better way to do it](https://godbolt.org/z/dzMePGcqj).